# Error running a Jest snapshot test using a custom snapshot serializer - jest-styled-components

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, styled-components, snapshot

I have a react app built with Create-React-app. I am trying to add a unit test to one of the components with an inline snapshot test. Along with the usual suspects, I have `styled-components`, `jest-styled-components` and `Prettier` installed as dev dependencies. I have added 'jest-styled-components' as a snapshotSerializer to my jest config in package.json.

I am getting the following error running the unit test -

```
    PrettyFormatPluginError: plugins[p].test is not a functionTypeError: plugins[p].test is not a function

  15 |   );
  16 | 
> 17 |   expect(container).toMatchInlineSnapshot();
     |                     ^
  18 | });
  19 | 
  20 | test("it renders empty cart message", () => {

  at findPlugin (node_modules/pretty-format/build/index.js:343:22)
  at prettyFormat (node_modules/pretty-format/build/index.js:523:22)
  at Object.toMatchInlineSnapshot (node_modules/expect/build/index.js:342:33)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/cart-dropdown/__tests__/cart-dropdown.js:17:21)
```

I can't figure out what is going wrong. Please help.

```
// package.json
...
"devDependencies": {
        "@testing-library/dom": "^6.11.0",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.0.0",
        "@testing-library/react": "^9.4.0",
        "jest-styled-components": "^7.0.0",
        "prettier": "^1.19.1"
      },
      "jest": {
        "snapshotSerializers": [
          "jest-styled-components"
        ]
      }
```

---

```
// unit test
import React from "react";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import CartDropdown from "../cart-dropdown";

test("it renders", () => {
  const mockHistory = jest.fn();
  const mockDispatch = jest.fn();

  const { container, debug } = render(
    <CartDropdown
      cartItems={[]}
      history={mockHistory}
      dispatch={mockDispatch}
    />
  );

  expect(container).toMatchInlineSnapshot();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing the `snapshotSerializers` entry from jest config and adding the `jest-styled-components` import into the test file resolved this issue.

```
// unit test
import React from "react";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import CartDropdown from "../cart-dropdown";

//add the below and remove entry for snapshotSerializers in jest config
import 'jest-styled-components'

test("it renders", () => {
  const mockHistory = jest.fn();
  const mockDispatch = jest.fn();

  const { container, debug } = render(
    <CartDropdown
      cartItems={[]}
      history={mockHistory}
      dispatch={mockDispatch}
    />
  );

  expect(container).toMatchInlineSnapshot();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the snapshotSerializers entry from jest config (Package.json) error will be gone